# puppet apply error: Could not find default node or by name with 'uys0115' on node uys0115

Tags: puppet

I have installed puppet on two nodes, and the server node hostname is "uys0115", and the cient node hostname is "uys0119", and the server node have siged the client node. When I exec the commad: `puppet cert list --all`, we can see:

```
+ "uys0115" (24:55:95:77:8E:60:33:77:C8:D4:74:EA:01:21:BD:5A)
+ "uys0119" (86:53:1B:81:E5:4F:88:23:E8:34:E1:AB:03:D4:AE:7C)
```

The puppet main directory is /etc/puppet/, I have write an example and the organization of files as follows:

```
/etc/puppet/--
             |-/manifests/site.pp
             |-/modules/test/--  
                              |-/files/text.txt
                              |-/manifests/init.pp
                              |-/manifests/test.pp
```

The code in `/etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp` is:

```
class test1 {
package { "bison":
        ensure=>"installed",
}
exec { "puppet test":
        command=>"/bin/touch /tmp/puppet-test",
}
file { "/tmp/test.txt":
        ensure => "present",
        source => "puppet:///modules/test/test.txt"
}
}
```

and the code in `/etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/init.pp` is just `import "*"`;
and the code in `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp` as follows:

```
import "test"
node default {
        include "test1"
}
```

When I in the client node uys0119 and exec the command `puppet agent --test --server uys0115`.
It executed successfully and created two files puppet-test and test.txt in the directory /tmp/.
In the server node when I exec the command `puppet apply site.pp`, it also executed successfully and created two files. However, the terminal out put two warning messages:

```
warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
warning: Host is missing hostname and/or domain: uys0115
```

When I changed the code in `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp` as follows:

```
import "test"
node "uys0119" {
        include "test1"
}
```

and exec the command `puppet apply site.pp` in the server node, it failed an output the error messages:

```
warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
warning: Host is missing hostname and/or domain: uys0115
warning: Host is missing hostname and/or domain: uys0115
Could not find default node or by name with 'uys0115' on node uys0115
```

But the client node can sucessfully exec the command `puppet agent --test --server uys0115` too. Can anybody explain that?
If I want to the server node send some repuests to the client nodes and drive some client  nodes responses the server and procduces results. How can I do when uses puppet? Can somebody give me an example? thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 4):

The server puppet serves as both puppet master and puppet node.

When you edited site.pp as below:

```
import "test"
node default {
    include "test1"
}
```

all puppet nodes connect to puppet master will do operations defined in class "test1". So you found two files in both `uys0115` and `uys0119`(treat as a puppet node).

When changed your site.pp to the following:

```
import "test"
node "uys0119" {
        include "test1"
}
```

puppet node `uys0115` can not find its definition in site.pp (because it only defines `uys0119`) and puppet master output error info like this:

```
Could not find default node or by name with 'uys0115' on node uys0115
```

Here is a modified site.pp can eliminate this error:

```
import "test"
node "uys0119" {
        include "test1"
}
node "uys0115" {
        include "test1"
}
```

In puppet master/slave mode, you'd better use fqdn such as `uys0115.localdomain`, then the following warning will not show

```
warning: Host is missing hostname and/or domain: uys0115
```